# Unique radio name in php while loop

Tags: php, html

Well, I've following Php code which generate a table with radio button so that user can select only one radio button in **EVERY** row. But to select only one radio button in **Every** row it's must be a unique name in **EVERY** row, Right ? But I can't get any idea how do i set a unique name in while loop. Can you guys give me any idea or solutions ?

**Php code:**

```
$action = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."?class=$class_from";  
echo "<form method='post' action='$action' name='attendence'/>";
echo "<table width='100%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class='tdhead' valign='top' width='200'><b>Student Name</b></td>";    
echo "<td class='tdhead' valign='top' width='250'><b>Roll No</b>
</td>";             
echo "<td class='tdhead' valign='top' width='250'><b>Class Name</b>
</td>";             
echo "<td class='tdhead' valign='top' width='200'><b>Present / Not present</b>
</td>";                 
echo "<td class='tdhead' valign='top' width='200'>Check All <input type= 'checkbox' 
onclick='checkAll(this)' /></td>";                  
echo "</tr>";


while($res2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
{

$sname = inputvalid($res2['sname']);
$roll = inputvalid($res2['roll']);
$class = inputvalid($res2['class']);

echo "<tr>";                
echo "<td class='tdhead2' valign='top'>$sname</td>";
echo "<td class='tdhead2' valign='top'>$roll</td>";
echo "<td class='tdhead2' valign='top'>$class</td>";        
echo "<td class='tdhead2' valign='top'>
<input type='radio' name='ch[]' value='1' />&nbsp;<input type='radio' name='ch[]' 
value='1' />
</td>";                     
echo "<td class='tdhead2' valign='top'>&nbsp;</td>";                
echo "</tr>";               

}

echo "<tr>";                
echo "<td class='tdhead2'>&nbsp;</td>";
echo "<td class='tdhead2'>&nbsp;</td>";
echo "<td class='tdhead2'>&nbsp;</td>";             
echo "<td class='tdhead2'>&nbsp;</td>";
echo "<td class='tdhead2'><input type='submit' value='Record' name='Submit' 
class='submit' /></td>";                
echo "</tr>";               

echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
```

Thanks for your help.

**Update:**

```
echo "<td class='tdhead2' valign='top'>";
echo '<input type="radio" name="ch'.$counter++.'[]" value="1">';
echo "&nbsp;";
echo '<input type="radio" name="ch'.$counter.'[]" value="0">';
echo "</td>";
```

Comment: Both your radio buttons have `value='1'` change the second to `value='2'` - the names must be the same but not the value. I.e.: `<input type='radio' name='ch[]' value='1' />&nbsp;<input type='radio' name='ch[]' value='2' />` - and you probably don't need the `[]` - those are mostly used for checkboxes for use in multiple choices. However you may need it `[]` for your DB work.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Problem with that is radio buttons with the same name are all considered part of the same radio group. Meaning you can only select one radio button on the entire page and not one per row.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Foe example it's showing me 3 rows with 2 radio button in every row then i can't click single button in every row. I can't select only one button ? I need in every row user can select only one button.

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure why you need the `[]`. Did you mean the ch to be an array? Like `$ch[...]`?

Comment: Either way, the values can't be the same. I can't elaborate any more than that. DB work is not my "forté", but I do know forms, and radio buttons can't have the same value.

Comment: @MrLister Yes it's a array.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn That's what I said in my comment *"and you probably don't need the [] - those are mostly used for checkboxes for use in multiple choices."* - yet may still be required for DB work.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Um, radio buttons in the same group (same name) can have the same value, but it is pointless because you won't know which one was checked. What OP wants is for each row to have it's own radio group. which would mean each row has a unique name with 2 radio buttons with values 0 and 1. Each group can have the same values. Also, what does a radio button have to do with "DB work"?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Well sure you do, when both radios are in the same group (name).

Comment: @JonathanKuhn No, values within a radiogroup should be unique. Otherwise they'd be useless.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Yes I agree. That "is" [what I said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703398/unique-radio-name-in-php-while-loop?noredirect=1#comment27555985_18703398), I do believe. As for the DB work, see the [answer give below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18703454/1415724) that's what I was referring to. Thus, the counter in the answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You are mis-understanding something. OP currently has all the radio buttons named the same. As in one group for all radio buttons on the page. What they don't know is how to add a counter to make each row have a separate group. They just want to know how to add a counter to the radio name for each loop. That has nothing to do with the value. The values 0 and 1 are fine within each radio group like they currently have.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I understand that. I wasn't going for "Gold" here, I was merely stating that the radio button values of the same group, cannot have the "same value". That's all. Let's just let it go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making the name just `ch[]` you can make the name `ch[SOME_UNIQUE_VALUE]` for each row. Usually something like an id number is used. Perhaps `$roll` if that is unique to each student. That will also allow you to know which id the radio button pertains to. On form submit, you can `foreach($_POST['ch'] as $id=>$value)` and get the id out.

Edit:

Example code:

```
//start the counter variable
$counter = 1;
while($res2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
{

    $sname = inputvalid($res2['sname']);
    $roll = inputvalid($res2['roll']);
    $class = inputvalid($res2['class']);

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='tdhead2' valign='top'>$sname</td>";
    echo "<td class='tdhead2' valign='top'>$roll</td>";
    echo "<td class='tdhead2' valign='top'>$class</td>";
    echo "<td class='tdhead2' valign='top'>";

    //echo each radio with the counter for this row
    echo "<input type='radio' name='ch_{$counter}[]' value='0' />&nbsp;";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='ch_{$counter}[]' value='1' />";

    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td class='tdhead2' valign='top'>&nbsp;</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    //add one to the counter
    $counter++;
}
```

Please note, unless you do like I suggested above, you will not be able to know which student each radio group goes to. You can assume that the radio buttons on group row 1 belongs to the student in row 1, but you might not know which student is in row 1. Which is why I suggest you put a unique id that goes with each student with each radio button instead of a counter.

Comment: @Alex Added an example.

Comment: Oh, Thank you so much. It's Perfect. Exactly what i want. Thanks.

Comment: I got your suggestion @Jonathan Kuhn.

Answer (score 2):

you can set a variable counter:

```
$counter = 1;
while($res2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){
  echo '<input type="radio" name="ch'.$counter++.'[]" value="'.$counter++.'">';
}
```

Comment: Hello, tonoslfx, now i can select all radio button. but i want to select only 1 radio buttion in every row.

Comment: @Alex Make the second radio button name just `$counter`, not `$counter++`. So the first one has the name `$counter++` and the second one has the name `$counter`. Also, just make the values `0` and `1` like you had before.

Comment: Within the same row , the name of the radio button should be the same.Every row should have a different radio button name

Comment: Ok @JonathanKuhn I'm trying it.

Answer (score 0):

You can store a counter `$count` and increase it after each iteration. Or if you have some unique id from the database per row (for example the primary_key), you can use that instead.`$id = $res['id']`

Then concat that value to the `name=ch".$id."...`

Answer (score 0):

you should use student name as an unique array and put that value in the name=""
and it will auto increment according to the name and you can only choose single option at single row.
try this :

```
<input type='radio' name='<?php echo $res2['sname'];?>' value='0' />&nbsp;";
<input type='radio' name='<?php echo $res2['sname'];?>' value='1' />";
```

this solutio will work.because it work's for me in an attendance system.