# Why is my upvotes column being updated with +2 instead of +1 and why are all upvote buttons updating the image with id of 1?

Tags: php, sql

I'm adding upvote/downvote buttons under every uploaded image so I can create a voting system, however, 2 problems have arisen. The first is that the function updates the upvotes with +2 instead of +1 for some reason and the second one is that every button on every image updates the image with id of 1. Here's my code:

```
<?php

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM image"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $getResult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    $numberOfResults = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $resultsPerPage = 5;
    $numberOfPages = ceil($numberOfResults/$resultsPerPage);

    if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
        $page = 1;
    } else {
        $page = $_GET['page'];
    }

    $currentPageResults = ($page-1)*$resultsPerPage;

    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM image ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$currentPageResults.','.$resultsPerPage;
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

    while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) { 
        echo    "<div class='imageContainer'>" 
                ."<h1>".$row["name"].'</h1>' 
                .'<div class="stickyImageContainer"><a href="imageInfo.php?image='.$row["path"].'"><img class="uploadedImg" src="uploads/'.$row["path"] .'" alt="Random image" /></a> 
                </div></div>';
        echo    "<form id='upvoteImage' method='POST' action='".upvoteImage($conn)."'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'>
                    <button id='upvoteImage' type='submit' name='upvoteImage'>Upvote</button>
                </form>";
        echo $row['id'];

        echo    "<form id='downvoteImage' method='POST' action=''>
                    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'>
                    <button id='downvoteImage' type='submit' name='downvoteImage'>Downvote</button>
                </form>";  
    }


    echo '<div class="imageContainer">';
    for ($page=1; $page<=$numberOfPages; $page++) {
        echo '<div class="pagination"><a href="index.php?page='.$page.'"><p id="paginationP">'.$page.'</p></a></div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
?>
```

And here's the logic for when the button is clicked.

```
<?php

    include 'db.inc.php';

    function upvoteImage($conn) {
        if (isset($_POST['upvoteImage'])){

            $imageId = $_POST['id'];

            $sql2 = "UPDATE image SET upvotes = upvotes + 1 WHERE id='$imageId'";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

            header("Location: ../index.php");

        }
    }

?>
```

I just found out that upvotes are updated with the amount of images I have uploaded, so If I have 4 images, it would be updated with +4. I can only assume that I've somehow screwed the pooch with the loop. How am I supposed to echo the buttons under every image if I don't put the button in the loop?

Comment: I think that all your forms are submiting. But your solutions isn't very good here. I would suggest you to use AJAX for that so you don't need to print so much forms

Comment: I just realized the code executes as many times as there are images in the database, however, I'm not sure how to fix it since I have to keep it in the loop so I can display the forms under every image.

Comment: As many times as there are images in the database or as many times as there are images in that page ?

Comment: Well this page is displaying all images in the database with newer ones on top.

Small correction, it updates the upvotes by a maximum of 5 even though I have 6 images uploaded now, which means that the pagination might have something to do with this.

Comment: Does the same thing happen with downvotes?

Comment: Yes that means that all your forms are being submited.

Comment: Yeah, same thing.

Comment: I mean I don't simultaneously get upvotes AND downvotes when I click one of the forms. I meant that if I click downvote, my downvote column also gets updates with + amount of images.

Comment: It sounds like ajax would work here. On another note, you should use actual column names in the queries instead of `SELECT *FROM ...`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try putting some unique identifier in the button name?
See this line of code:

`<button id='upvoteImage' type='submit' name='upvoteImage'>Upvote</button>`.

You can refer to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703398/unique-radio-name-in-php-while-loop) to see an example of this being done. Once you do this for both up and down votes update with the new results please.